# How can one set the confidence level in the seqMK() function in the R package "pheno"?

Tags: r, package

Hello  I am using the seqMK() function in the “pheno” package for the first time and there is something puzzling me.
seqMK function - RDocumentation
I can use the function OK, and the “built-in” confidence level of 5% is what I need to use at the moment, but I can’t see any way of changing the confidence level, should one want to do that.  I’ve delved into the code for the function (pheno source: R/seqMK.R (rdrr.io)) , and also into the “tau” function (pheno source: R/tau.R (rdrr.io) )(the version in “pheno” which has an input of only one vector, as opposed the “tau” function in the “ircor” package, which needs two vector inputs), which is used by seqMK but nowhere can I see a way of tweaking so as to change the confidence level.  In the code there don’t seem to be any other called functions apart base R ones where the confidence levels might be generated. There also doesn’t seem to be a way of setting the confidence level directly when using seqMK, that is, you can’t write something like seqMK(x,alpha=0.01).
I may be missing something very obvious…  Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks, Nick Wray